# Test Connection for LinkedServer in SSMS failed on Client, not on the machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, linked-server

we are runninng a MS SQL 2005 Server and installed the Oracle driver 'Oracle Provider for OLE DB'
With this driver we setup successfull a "Linked Server" to an 'Oracle 10g Enterprise Database'.
Everything worked fine for serveral month without any problems.

Suddenly we cant connect anymore to the Linked Server and getting this ErrorMessage when we try a "Test Connection" from our Client
[image: Error Message LinkedServer]
Directly on the Machine we can use the LinkedServer without any Problems and everything (e.g. Test Connection, select * from openquery, and so on) work fine.
Also we can Ping and Tracert the Target Oracle Server from the Host and all Clients.
We reinstalled the driver and reboot the machine without any success.

At this Point we really dont know how to fix the Problem :(

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it ?

Best Regards, Ralf

Comment: Our IT colleague found a solution:  _ACTION(S) TO REACH 'BACK TO SERVICE':<
Reinstall
the ODAC Drivers .ODAC can't run inside the SQL-Instance. Configured ODAC Driver, DCOM MSDAINITIALIZE and Directory Permissions to allow ODAC run outside the SQL-Instance. It wok's well._

Answer (score -1):

ACTION(S) TO REACH 'BACK TO SERVICE':< Reinstall the ODAC Drivers .ODAC can't run inside the SQL-Instance. Configured ODAC Driver, DCOM MSDAINITIALIZE and Directory Permissions to allow ODAC run outside the SQL-Instance. It wok's well.